# Could I use LinkedIn to improve visibility WITHIN my company?

Tags: professionalism, promotion, linkedin, networking, international

I have a profile which I have not updated since early in my current job out of concerns that it might signal lack of loyalty. One of my greatest assets my superiors have lauded as a reason to promote me twice is that they trust me and that I was loyal to the company throughout multiple ups and downs. I never want to give the impression that I try to look elsewhere (and I actually never will).

The company is now expanding in new markets across the world and there is no established internal profile system.

Reading all the recent topics about the importance of visibility, I have also noticed that many new hires don't even know who I am nor that I am the "go-to" person for a number of areas (instead they ask my boss or team who often redirect to me) - I tend to be someone who doesn't like to "show off" - in fact, I think only very few people in the company know that I am a manager - so now I am a bit concerned about whether I should generally improve my exposure and let people know who I am :)

Most client-facing employees in the company have an up-to-date brushed up profile, so I was wondering if updating mine would not be seen negatively - and instead as a good way forward.

Comment: Be as loyal as you like, but I can assure you the loyalty won't be mirrored in times of serious difficulty - unless it's a very special business model(small, family fun etc) you remain nothing but a costly asset on a spreadsheet. You should update your profile both for internal visibility and because in this day and age we should ALL be ready to bail out at short notice.

Comment: You shouldn't expect your linked in profile to be enough to improess internally either. You need to be more visible within your company.